# Origin and usage of あせた

Tags: usage

I often hear "あせた" as in:

> パスワードわかんなくてあせた
>   作れなくてあせたわ
>   久々すぎて全然できなくてあせた

Is it only oral usage?
How should I write it in an email?
Does it make sense to ever spell it with kanji?
I always hear it as "あせた", can it be used in other tenses as well?

Comment: Is it not a shortening of 焦った？

Comment: @ssb: Could be! I have no idea about its origin and kanji, in fact. Also, I have no idea why this question gets downvoted. It is used in Japanese, so it should not be off-topic here.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes. But did you copy these sentences from somewhere or transcribe it? あせた usually refers to faded colors as far as I know.

Comment: It might be dialect, but I hear it often and it really sounds like あせた not あせった. I guess people don't write it, but there are still many Google occurrences if that proves anything: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6%E3%81%82%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%22

Comment: Interesting. Possibly ネット用語？

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the correct term and kanji is 焦った (to lose one's mind).

Thanks to ssb for the tip!

Comment: It seems peculiar to say what the "correct" word is when discussing a new slang word.  IMHO, 「あせる/汗る」 is correct in its own right though I would never use it myself.  Call one slang word "not correct" and we will be calling all slang words "not correct".

Comment: Besides, 汗る does not always mean 焦る.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya: Haha I got downvoted for using 汗る and now for not using it... Post a new answer.